# how to move image in kivy only when image is pressed on

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy and I would like for an image to move only when the image is pressed on, but currently, the image moves if anywhere in the screen is pressed. Below is my code!

main.py

```
class Ball(Image):
velocity = NumericProperty(0)


def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.source = "icons/ball.png"
    self.velocity = 275
    super().on_touch_down(touch)

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    self.source = "icons/ball.png"
    super().on_touch_up(touch)


class MainApp(App):
    GRAVITY = 300


def move_ball(self, time_passed):
    ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
    ball.y = ball.y + ball.velocity * time_passed
    ball.velocity = ball.velocity - self.GRAVITY * time_passed
```

main.kv

```
Ball:
        source: "icons/ball.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 500
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        id: ball
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if the `press` is actually on the `Image`. To do that you can use `collide_point()` as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html):

> on_touch_down(), on_touch_move(), on_touch_up() don’t do any sort of
> collisions. If you want to know if the touch is inside your widget,
> use collide_point().

So try changing `on_touch_down()` to :

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
        self.velocity = 275
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```

And similar with `on_touch_up()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but now if I press on different parts of the screen like in the corner nothing happens which is what I wanted but, If I press closer to the image not exactly on the Image it still moves. How can I make it so that only exactly when it's pressed on the image it moves.

Comment: The `collide_point()` determines if the click is on the `Image` widget (`Ball`). But what you see is the `texture`, which may not fill the entire `Ball` widget. To try to make the texture match the `Ball` widget, try adding `allow_stretch: True`. You may want to also add `keep_ratio: True` to keep a ball looking round. And make sure the `Ball` aspect ratio matches the source image aspect ratio.

Comment: how do I do that? can you please help me! Thank You

Comment: Just add the `keep_ratio: True` and `allow_stretch: True` to your `kv` rule for `Ball`.

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work.